# Блок в twig по умолчанию

Tags: symfony3, twig

Всем добра.
Недавно начал изучать Symfony 3
У меня возник вопрос
в лейауте у меня есть два блока

```
{% block nav-panel %}

    {#КАТЕГОРИИ#}

{% endblock %}
{% block body %}

{% endblock %}
```

Боди каждый раз разный приходит из метода
а " nav-panel" у меня категории товаров
Захарткодить его (nav-panel) в самом лейауте я не могу(так-как категории могут добавиться или удалиться)
но не буду же из каждого метода отправлять категории.
как реализовать это задачу

Answer (score 1):

Разобрался.
Помог knplabs/knp-menu-bundle